# MongoDB: db.collection.watch on sharded clusters

Tags: mongodb

I'm interested in [db.collection.watch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) feature on MongoDB sharded clusters.

Did you have any problems with it in the production environment?

To guarantee total ordering of changes, for each change notification the mongos [checks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/change-streams-production-recommendations/#sharded-clusters) with each shard to see if the shard has seen more recent changes.

Is it possible to reduce this checks? I don't want to see changes from all shards. Maybe $match filter could help me

Thank you!